# Socket.io - listener must be a function on socket.io event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to rewrite my socket.io server in order to dodge the "callback hell" thing. Now I'm trying to listen for an event, and instead of passing an anonymus function as callback, I want to pass a function exported by a module.

Basically I want to do this

```
socket.on('joinChat', myFuncExportedByModule(/* stuff */));
```

Instead of this

```
socket.on('joinChat', function() {
    /* stuff */
});
```

As soon as I tried to invoke myFuncExportedByModule, node sent me back an "TypeError: listener must be a function".

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you export your function? How did you imported it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error is you're not passing a function, but executing it.

Try remove parenthesis:

```
socket.on('joinChat', myFuncExportedByModule);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was obvious. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: No problem, it can happen